# How can I select a split element and manipulate it DOM with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have split an array and now I want to select and manipulate one or more specific elements split.

```
function displayAlignment(data) {
    let html = "";
    html += `<h3>Alignments</h3>`
    for (let i = 0; i < data.results[1].desc.split(/\n/).length; i++) {
        html += `<p>${data.results[1].desc.split(/\n/)[i]}</p>`
    }
    document.querySelector(`.content-text`).innerHTML = html
}
```

I want to get `data.results[1].desc.split(/\n/)[4]`, for example, and change its property style: color, font size, etc.
How can I select and manipulate it?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the HTML element doesn't have an id or a class you cannot reference it using a string. If it has, you can extract the id of the element and then manipulate it like a normal DOM element.

Comment: what is data.result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either:

i) have a condition on the loop `(if i === 4)` and add the style inline. aka `<p style="here">${data.results[1].desc.split(/\n/)[i]}</p>`

ii) add classes or id's and use CSS

iii) grab it with javascript with selector or class/id if you have given one and then apply the style `document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`, the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) to read more.

Hopefully there are plenty of ways. Let us know !

Comment: That was fast. Thank you very much. Since I am putting the results into a p tag, all the elements go in at once, so I can not define a class or id for that specific paragraph. Or at least I don't know how to do it. I am gonna give a try with the condition solution. It may work as I intend. I will let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome. I think you will add several paragraphs and not just one. For i==10 you will have 10 paragraphs. Then you can specifically point to the n-th paragraph with CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp Kindly mark as correct if something of the above works.

Comment: I could not use the condition solution, because I couldn't replace the paragraph once first listed to the new styled paragraph with the condition. Maybe there is a way, but I couldn't find it. I solved the problem using nth-child though. I was able to point the specific paragraph and change it. Thank you very much for showing that out. 
If I may ask you one more thing: how can I style, let's say, the first 2 or 3 words of that paragraph? Is there a way? Thank you again.

Comment: hmm interesting question you need to wrap around the first words a `span`. You probably need to save the line in a temp variable then figure out the words and wrap the span around it, then pass it to `html`. Better write another function for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with childNodes.

```
 let c = document.querySelector(".content-text").childNodes;
 c[5].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

I can now also set an ID for it.